# TypeError: 'Dash' object is not callable

Tags: python, plotly-dash, uvicorn, asgi

I am trying to run a dash app in a uvicorn server. The app is very simple, just displays the text 'hello' to the screen. The code is as follows:

```
from dash import Dash, html
dash_app = Dash(__name__)
dash_app.layout = html.Div(id='main-layout', children=["hello"])
```

If I run the app using `dash_app.run()` the app runs as expected and I can visit the page on localhost.

However, I am trying to run the app using uvicorn. The command that I am using to start the server looks like this:

```
uvicorn uvicorn_test.__main__:dash_app
```

I am running the main file in that exists in a directory called uvicorn_test.

When I run the uvicorn command, the server starts up, but when I try to access the web page, I am getting an error that says "TypeError: 'Dash' object is not callable"

Comment: Should you be passing `app.run` and not `dash_app`?

Comment: @RandomDavis if I do that the app runs in the development dash server. My goal is to have it run with uvicorn for deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uvicorn is used to run ASGI (as fastapi apps) servers and not WSGI servers (as Flask apps);

In the context of Dash, we need to use GUNICORN instead of UVICORN;

To be able to run your code you need to:

`server = dash_app.server`

and to run it in your context you need to do:

`gunicorn app:server -b 0.0.0.0:8050`

Where app, is the `app.py` file;

Let me know if it works.
Leonardo