# TypeError: 'Div' object is not callable

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm working with plotly to visualize data this is the code I have so far:

**input**:

```
from dash import Dash, html

#initialize app
app = Dash(__name__)

# App layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(children='Hello World')
])


#run app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.layout(debug=True)
```

**output**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<private>\<private>\<private>\Documents\pythonVisualize\app.py", line 14, in <module>
    app.layout(debug=True)
TypeError: 'Div' object is not callable
```

Why am I getting this error? While this is a copy and paste from [Plotly](https://dash.plotly.com/tutorial) How can I fix this?

After running this using: python .\app.py, I'm supposed to get an link where I'll use ctrl + click and it should open a page showing Hello world:

This is the supposed output

[image: Screenshot of window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding app.run() in your main. This is from the documentation (https://dash.plotly.com/tutorial) .

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

You'll find further explanations and ways to run it as explained in the post: [TypeError: 'Dash' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73719291/13339621) .

Comment: Man, I really appreciate it. Thank you so much. So, they made a mistake on their side. Thanks for helping I'm getting the output as expected.